# Skip over null JSON values when performing regex search

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm writing some data to a file like this:

```
with open(tab_json, 'w') as f:
    print('Saving JSON file')
    json.dump(json_out, f)
```

Then I read it in later:

```
with open(tab_json, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

And eventually write to csv. The problem is the json has some None values, and when I try to iterate I get an error from re.search:

```
for list_item in data:
    for dict_item in list_item:
        if count == 0:
            header = dict_item.keys()
            csvwriter.writerow(header)
            count += 1
        for x, y in dict_item.items():
            if re.search('.*\u200b.*', y):
```

The error is:

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

That's because of the None values. How to handle that?

As you can see I'm not using Pandas. I could but hoping I don't have to rewrite the code.

Comment: You could just change that check to `if y is not None and re.search('.*\u200b.*', y):`. Do you need to do anything in the case that `y` is `None`?

Comment: It'd be great if you showed example inputs and outputs